# If $E(z)= \sum _{n=0 }^{\infty }\frac {z ^n } {n! } $, how is $E(0) $ defined?

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis, exponential-function

If $E(z)= \sum _{n=0 }^{\infty }\frac {z ^n } {n! }  $, how is $E(0) $ defined?

The exponential function for complex $z $ is defined in Rudin's principles as the power series $ \sum _{n=0 }^{\infty }\frac {z ^n } {n! }  $, I cannot see that it is clear how this function is defined for $z=0 $. How is this typically done?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Just take the convention $0^0=1$ and your power serie is well defined for $z=0$

Comment: In general, when we write out functions as series, $z^0=1$, for any $z$. This is notational convention.

Answer (score 1):

$$E(z)=1+z+\frac{z^2}{2!}+\frac{z^3}{3!}+\cdots\\
E(0)=1+0/1+0^2/2+0^3/6\cdots=1$$